# Create a virtualenv with fish shell on Mac OS?

Tags: python, django, terminal, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual environment for a django project. I already installed it with pip3. When I try to create the environment through :

```
❰C❙~/meltingpot(git:main)❱✔≻ virtualenv meltingpot
```

I get this error

```
fish: Unknown command virtualenv
```

Can somebody please show me how can I create virtualenv successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
virtualenv venv
```

Or:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Next:

```
source venv/bin/activate.fish
```

Comment: I get the same error fish: Unknown command virtualenv